# ReferenceError: CustomEvent is not defined in NextJS project

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm getting error: `ReferenceError: CustomEvent is not defined`.
I know CustomEvent is available in browser only (client side), but I'm trying using this function as event:

```
const mouseEnterHandler =  () => {
  eventDispatcher('cursor', {
    label: 'test',
  })
}

onMouseEnter={mouseEnterHandler()}

export const eventCreator = (name: string, params: Record<string, any>): CustomEvent => {
  const event = new CustomEvent(name, {
    detail: params
  })

  return event
}

export const eventDispatcher = (name: string, params: Record<string, any>): CustomEvent => {
  const event: CustomEvent = eventCreator(name, params)

  document.dispatchEvent(event)

  return event
}
```

Comment: `onMouseEnter` expect a function, so try `onMouseEnter={mouseEnterHandler}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function SomePage({ props }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('test-event', (event) => {
      console.log('test-event', event);
    });

    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('test-event', { detail: { test: 'testing' } }));
  });

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Put it in a `useEffect` hook and it will work.